# Add to cart / checkout performance issues

Tags: mysql, magento-community

I am getting slow page loads (upwards of 7 - 10 seconds) when a visitor adds a product to their cart. The rest of my site loads quickly having already implemented: APC, MEMCACHED and just recently VARNISH with the TURPENTINE module.

The magento 1.8.0 installation is running on a dedicated server with dual Xeon processors, 12GB RAM, SAS RAID 5 configuration.

CentOS 6.5 64bit (all applicable updates)
PHP: 5.3.3
MySQL: 5.1.71

I've run the MySQL Tuner script (https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl) + MySQL Tuning Primer Script (https://launchpad.net/mysql-tuning-primer/+download) and implemented all the recommendations.

Troubleshooting:

Enabled the Profiler in the Admin panel and have discovered a few bottle necks that seem to be slowing down the add to cart:

```
CODE PROFILER   TIME    CNT   EMALLOC   REALMEM
mage             7.9598   1      0         0 
.
.
mage::dispatch::controller::action::checkout_cart_index 7.9071 1 0 0     
.
DISPATCH EVENT:sales_quote_address_collect_totals_before   4.7420 2 2,418,224 3,145,728 
.
OBSERVER: auto_add_on_coupon_insertion 4.7411 2 2,388,872 3,145,728
```

Slow Query Log:

```
# Query_time: 4.962430  Lock_time: 0.000184 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 52391
SET timestamp=1390674352;
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e.entity_id) FROM `catalog_product_flat_2` AS `e`
INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON      cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id='2' AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id = '2'
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 WHERE (((((e.news_from_date <= '2014-01-25 23:59:59') OR (e.news_from_date IS null))))) AND (((((e.news_to_date >= '2014-01-25 00:00:00') OR (e.news_to_date IS null))))) AND ((`e`.`news_from_date` IS not null) OR (`e`.`news_to_date` IS not null));
```

Given the above results of the Profiler and Slow Query Log, what would be the next recommended course of action? How can I get the add to cart load times down? I'm sure a lot of people can benefit from this.

Note: This is with zero load, only myself performing actions in the front end.

**UPDATE (AM)**

After more tweaking of the my.cnf the site was still sluggish on Add to Cart.  This morning when trying to login to the admin panel, it was taking over 5 minutes to login at which point I restarted mysqld. Still the same. Add to Cart was the same as well (5 minutes +).

I cleared out the

```
/var/cache/ 
/var/locks/ 
/var/session/
```

Now the site is lightening fast here are the new profiler results:

```
mage 0.7792 1 0 0
```

**UPDATE 2 (PM)**

Site has slowed back down over the course of the day:

```
mage 8.4715 1 0 0
```

Clearing the /var/cache returned it back to .7 seconds on add to cart..

Why would this make such a huge difference in performance? Is it recommended to periodically clear out these directories and restart the services?

Cron is running regularly. Thanks!

Comment: Caching won't help you in this case. It's probably an issue with MySQL. Did you check your slow query log? Turn it on to see what's happing: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/slow-query-log.html

Comment: @SanderMangel Yes it is enabled, I will edit my post to include the last query that coincides with the profiler. Thanks SR

Comment: How many products/SKU's do you have in that installation?

Comment: That *might* be the problem. I'm not saying Magento CE can't handle a large amount of SKUs but it does slow it down considerably. You could test that by setting up a test environment and only adding 5k SKUs for example.

Comment: Hypothetical: If the server runs faster with 5k SKU's, then what is the solution for tuning the 50k SKU environment? More processing power? More RAM? Is there a way to by pass the query of all products to simply add 1 item to the cart? All usage data when monitoring the server shows little impact under add to cart condition.

Comment: You could tweak your MySQL server setup. Take a look at this wiki: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/168/optimising_your_web_stack_performance_for_magento#mysqlinnodb_configuration

Comment: @SanderMangel thanks, I have followed this and every possible article I could find about MySQL performance and Magento.  Clearing out 3 directories seems to have cured the problem, now I'm just trying to understand why. Thanks, SR

Comment: hm didn't know that would be an issue on dev. Make sure your magento cronjob is running so the session cleanup tasks are running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much troubleshooting, the problem appears to be the inefficiencies of the Magento caching system.

The implementation of  [TURPENTINE](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/2984.html) (to complement VARNISH) ended up accelerating and making the problem more pronounced as the Site Crawler was Enabled to warm the cache.

Came across [this article](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/improving-the-file-cache-backend/) describing the issue I was having and provided a solution. Implementing REDIS has cured the issue and has improved performance on "Add to cart" as well as load times on cached pages.

Answer (score 2):

`OBSERVER: auto_add_on_coupon_insertion 4.7411 2 2,388,872 3,145,728`

seems to be a big contributor. Default Magento 1.8 does not have such an event observer. As a first step I would suggest going through any installed custom extension to see if disabling it solves the slowness.

Comment: This is a good point, however this morning I have updated the scenario as after clearing out the /var/cache/, /var/session/ and /var/locks/ the site is now loading bellow 1 second on add to cart. Just the same I have contacted the developer. Thank you SR.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to truncate your `quote` tables...

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
TRUNCATE TABLE sales_flat_quote;
TRUNCATE TABLE sales_flat_quote_address;
TRUNCATE TABLE sales_flat_quote_address_item;
TRUNCATE TABLE sales_flat_quote_item;
TRUNCATE TABLE sales_flat_quote_item_option;
TRUNCATE TABLE sales_flat_quote_payment;
TRUNCATE TABLE sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Comment: having a lot of legacy data in the quote tables might cause the issue but as OP posted the issue seems to be a query of 4 seconds on the catalog tables